# Dockerfile COPY creates undesired subdirectory in image

Tags: docker

I want to create a Docker container and I wrote image. Everything works great except the COPY command where I got confused. My Dockerfile:

```
RUN HOME=/home/ros rosdep update

RUN mkdir -p /home/ros/workspace

# Copy the files
COPY $PWD/src/a_file /home/ros/workspace/src
COPY $PWD/src/b_file /home/ros/workspace/src
```

`a_file` is a directory like a `b_file`. When I try to copy these directories into a newly created directory called `/home/ros/workspace/src` I want `a_file` and `b_file` to be both inside `/home/ros/workspace/src`. Instead of this, I get another `src` directory `/home/ros/workspace/src/src`) and the contents of `a_file` and `b_file` are inside that directory.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As mentioned in other answers, `$PWD`refers to the image context. 
Try to use `.` instead.

To setup your working directory, use `WORKDIR`

Also, both `a_file` and `b_file` are in `src/`

All in all, this should work (not tested):

```
FROM <your-base-image>
WORKDIR /home/ros

RUN rosdep update
RUN mkdir -p workspace

# Copy the files
COPY ./src workspace/src
```

Comment: Hi, I can't do the above code due to error in catkin_make which is quite specific to my problem but I did this instead:
COPY ./src /home/ros/workspace/
and got an error that /home/ros/workspace/src does not exist. I can't understand as I clearly just copied src directory

Comment: I guess you first have to create the `src` directory. I will update my answer.

Comment: Hmm, my a_file and b_file directories keep being added to src/src

Comment: After hours of editing my Dockerfile it finally worked. The problem was that I was copying the inner files of a_file and b_file and because both of them were located in src folder, Docker copied the whole src folder into a created container src folder.

Comment: Glad you made it @SteveMartin!

Answer (score 1):

In your Dockerfile, **PWD** variable refers to image context (i.e: inside the image).

From [COPY documentation](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#copy):

> paths of files and directories will be interpreted as relative to the source of the context of the build.

If `src` directories are in the root of your [build context](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/build/), your example it will be:

```
...
COPY src/a_file /home/ros/workspace/src
COPY src/b_file /home/ros/workspace/src
...
```